# Selecting and affecting elements within a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, loops

I am trying to select all instances of the "picture" element inside any divs with a class of "highlights". Here is an example of a section of a page with the picture element inside a "highlights" div...

```
<div class="row highlights">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="bx-adapt">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <figure class="pic square">
          <picture>

             Content in here

          </picture>
        </figure>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

After reviewing some questions similar to my own on the site, I figured the following Javascript would select all of the relevant picture elements and style them, but it does not. All I get is the success alert for each instance of the picture element.

```
$('picture').each(function(i, elm) {
  if($(elm).closest(".highlights").length > 0) {
    $('picture').css("border","10px solid red");
    alert("Success");
  }
 });
```

I must be incorrect in how I'm selecting the relevant picture elements but I'm not sure what the problem is. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

**edit**

Everyone's answers seem to be sound, but I suspect that the way the page is being generated won't allow me to select the picture element for some reason. I can select img's within the picture element (give them the red border), but not so with picture.

For some more context, the page I'm working on uses lazy load to sequentially load images on the page, but the page hangs on IE so I am trying to select elements that I believe to be causing most of the slow-down.

Comment: $('.highlights picture') would be probably better and an .each(){$(this).css...

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the style of `$('picture')`, and not the actual picture element `$(elm)`.

Try:

```
   $(elm).css("border","10px solid red")
```

instead.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you TheoretiCAL.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different selector

```
$('.highlights picture').each(function(i, elm) {
    $(elm).css("border","10px solid red");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.highlights picture').each( function( i, elm ) {
    $(elm).css("border", "10px solid red");
});
```

Should do the trick (;  Remember the jQuery element selector `$()` takes a css selector as an argument.  Also you were changing the border of every `<picture>` element by calling the `$('picture').css...`.

Comment: Thanks for that tip Brian.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a CSS approach:

```
div.highlights picture {
    border: 10px solid red;
}
```

Or if you must use jQuery, try this:

```
$('div.highlights picture').css('border','10px solid red');
```

**Note:** If DIVs are the only element types with class `.highlights`, then you can replace `div.highlights` with `.highlights`.

```css
div.highlights picture {
    border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row highlights">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="bx-adapt">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <figure class="pic square">
          <picture>

             Content in here

          </picture>
        </figure>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
  
  
<div class="row highlights">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="bx-adapt">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <figure class="pic square">
          <picture>

             Content in here 2

          </picture>
        </figure>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
  
<div class="row highlights">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="bx-adapt">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <figure class="pic square">
          <picture>

             Content in here 3

          </picture>
        </figure>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
  
<picture>
  PICTURE element not in `div.highlights`
</picture>
```

```js
$('div.highlights picture').css('border','10px solid red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  
<picture>
  PICTURE element not in `div.highlights`
</picture>
    <div class="row highlights">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="bx-adapt">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
            <figure class="pic square">
              <picture>

                 Content in here 0

              </picture>
            </figure>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>

<div class="row highlights">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="bx-adapt">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <figure class="pic square">
          <picture>

             Content in here 1

          </picture>
        </figure>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div> 
  
<div class="row highlights">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="bx-adapt">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <figure class="pic square">
          <picture>

             Content in here 2

          </picture>
        </figure>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
  
<div class="row highlights">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="bx-adapt">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <figure class="pic square">
          <picture>

             Content in here 3

          </picture>
        </figure>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. The goal of this was to be able to have a visual representation of the selected elements with JS, so I absolutely agree that CSS would be the best approach otherwise.

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept and upvote this answer if you found it useful.

Comment: I need more reputation to have my votes seen publicly but you have been upvoted. The thing is, I'm experiencing this issue where no matter what method I use, I cannot seem to select the picture element on my page. I suspect it has to do with how lazy loader is working behind the scenes. So, while this answers my question, it doesn't entirely solve the problem I'm having unfortunately.

Comment: Please make sure that all you tags, especially the DIVs, are properly closed. In the sample HTML you  provided, I had to add a `</div>` at the end to make the HTML valid.